# Dedicated swap on PCI SSD is mostly ignored by Linux

Tags: swap

My classmates and I have pooled resources together to build a small Ubuntu research server.

The server has 128gb of RAM and I put the swap space on a dedicated SSD connected on the PCI bus. (/dev/nvme0n1) Samsung 960 EVO. System is a second hand `Dell PowerEdge T430` with two processors.**

[image: swapMount]

I am able to `swapon` the ssd but Ubuntu 16.04 is not using it. Swappiness is at 85, and vfs_cache_pressure set to 50.

```
# swapon --show
NAME         TYPE      SIZE USED PRIO
/dev/nvme0n1 partition 477G   0B   -1

$cat /proc/sys/vm/swappiness && cat /proc/sys/vm/vfs_cache_pressure
85
50

$ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           125G         94G        8.8G         27M         22G         29G
Swap:          476G          0B        476G

# fdisk -l
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 477 GiB, 512110190592 bytes, 1000215216 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

$ ls /dev/nvme*
/dev/nvme0  /dev/nvme0n1
```

[image: htop]

#### Is there something about having swap on a dedicated disk that could be causing this?

#### Attempts to fix it.

- I have tried to `swapon` and `swapoff` to fix it
- I have also tried to swapon a partition (p1) created on the ssd instead of the entire drive itself
- I have tried to `mkswap /dev/nvme0n1` on the drive before `swapon` the disk

** All the RAM (4x32gb) is on the second processor (B1-B4) even-though the documentation says that the two CPUs must have identical RAM configurations. This was the only RAM seating that worked.

Comment: It is interesting that the `free -h` command shows 1 less Gb of RAM. Must be a bug.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are expecting?  You have still 29GB available, your "free -h" says so.  There is no reason for your machine to use swap.
Keep in mind "cache/buffers" are not considered "used".  The machine is just using RAM to speed up the machine, but that RAM is considered available.

Perhaps you need to read up on RAM https://www.linuxatemyram.com/

Swappiness is just a suggestion.  If there is no reason to put programs in swap, the kernel won't.

Comment: That site is funny. Thanks for explaining this to me. I guess I was being a noob.

Comment: @vidarlo Done with minor edits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely your problem stems from a misunderstanding on how to read RAM usage in Linux. You have still 29GB available, your "free -h" says so. There is no reason for your machine to use swap.

Keep in mind "cache/buffers" are not considered "used". The machine is just using RAM to speed up the machine, but that RAM is considered available.

Perhaps you need to read up on RAM [linuxatemyram.com](https://www.linuxatemyram.com/) usage in Linux.

Swappiness is just a suggestion. If there is no reason to put programs in swap, the kernel won't.